# swiftでsegmentedcontrolを用いてViewcontrollerを切り替える方法

Tags: ios, swift

swiftでsegmentedcontrolを用いてViewcontrollerを切り替えたいと思っているのですが、その際にstoryboardを使ったものではなくプログラムを実際に書いて実装していく方法が知りたいです。どのサイトを見てもstoryboardを使っていてよくわかりませんでした

Answer (score 1):

UIControlEventValueChangedのイベントを取得して、window.rootViewControllerを書き換えるか、naivgationController.viewControllersを書き換えるのが良いと思います